# Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: sql-server, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am constantly getting error `Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll` even though I have specified on `project - Properties - Run` this VM options: `-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\auth\x86"` That is the exact location where the `dll` exists.

[image]

Full error: `Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path`

What have I done wrong here?

**PS.** I have read all other questions around about this error, but most of them didn't included that line in the `project - Properties`.

Comment: Are you by any chance running a 64-bit JVM, so you need an x64 rather than an x86 DLL?

Comment: Is your library sqljdbc_auth.dll inside windows/system32 ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the dll really located at `-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\auth\x86"` ?

Try also forward-slashes
`-Djava.library.path="C:/Program Files/Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/auth/x86"`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.  Make sure you have both enu\auth\x86 and enu\auth\x64 as Jeroen alludes to above.  I've also had one case where I had to add sqljdbca_auth.dll to \Windows\SysWOW64